# How do I switch between local and global settings for the initial state of a C++11 RNG?

Tags: c++, c++11, prng

In the code given below, I would like to implement a flag (or something equally simple) that has the same effect as commenting out the *local* setting and using the *global* setting some times (yielding two different numbers in this example), and using the local setting at other times (yielding two identical numbers in this example).

I have tried the obvious "if" and "switch" structures without success.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random> 

void print();

std::seed_seq seed{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}; 
std::mt19937 rng(seed); // *global* initial state
std::uniform_real_distribution<> rand01(0, 1); 

int main()
{
    print();
    print();

    return 0; 
}

void print()
{
    std::mt19937 rng(seed); // *local* initial state
    std::cout << rand01(rng) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show *how* you have tried e.g. `if` or `switch`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a *ternary* and a *reference*:

```
std::mt19937& ref = flag ? rng : local;
```

Here, `flag` is the condition to test, `rng` is the "global" random object, and `local` is the more localised one.

Binding a reference to the result of a ternary is syntactically valid: you can't do it using an `if` statement, or similar as those are not *expressions* of the correct type.

From that point, use `ref`. This will be valid so long as `rng` and `local` remain in scope.